# make onHover affect only one element in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

im trying to show a button everytime a string is hovered, what im doing is working fine, but when i hover the string it will show every button in available string, i tried to pass the key but it still wont work, here is my code

```
const _showButton = () => {
    setButton(true);
  };

  const _hideButton = () => {
    setButton(false);
  };

  const _options = (uid) => {
    return isButton ? <button key={uid}> ... </button> : null;
  };


return(
 {isProject.map((p) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Typography onMouseEnter={_showButton} onMouseLeave={_hideButton}>
                  {p.title} {_options(p.uid)}
                </Typography>
              </div>
            );
          })}
)
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks before, i know this question might be already asked before but i cant find the one that use a functional like me instead a class

Comment: What is `isButton`? Seems like it's a single value shared across all your buttons. Same for `setButton`. That really should be created for each button separately.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like `button` state is only one boolean, who controlled all mapped elements.

So you have two options,

First, change `button` state to an array

```
const [ button, setButton ] = useState(Array.from({ length: isProject.length }, _ => false))
```

and pass the index to functions and use specific slot to determine if a button should be visible

```
const _toggleButton = (i) => {
    setButton(prev => prev.map((bool, idx) => i == idx ? !bool : bool);
  };

const _options = (uid, i) => {
    return button[i] ? <button key={uid}> ... </button> : null;
  };

return(
 {isProject.map((p, i) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Typography onMouseEnter={()=>_toggleButton(i)} onMouseLeave={()=>_toggleButton(i)}>
                  {p.title} {_options(p.uid, i)}
                </Typography>
              </div>
            );
          })}
)
```

Second is refactor mapped elemto it own component and declare state there, that way each elem will have it own state

```
{isProject.map((p) => <Component p={p} />  )}


function Component({p}) {
const [button, setButton] = useState(false)
const _showButton = () => {
    setButton(true);
  };

  const _hideButton = () => {
    setButton(false);
  };

  const _options = (uid) => {
    return button ? <button key={uid}> ... </button> : null;
  };
 return (
              <div>
                <Typography onMouseEnter={_showButton} onMouseLeave={_hideButton}>
                  {p.title} {_options(p.uid)}
                </Typography>
              </div>
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because _option runs in map and iterate over the whole list and the state is a single state which enables it for every item. You should consider setting "p's uid" in state variable (instead of true/false) and compare uid with the one is state in "_options" method.

```
const [selectedButtonUid, setSelectedButtonUid] = useState('');

const _showButton = (uid) => {
    setSelectedButtonUid(uid);
  };

  const _hideButton = () => {
    setSelectedButtonUid('');
  };

  const _options = (uid) => {
    return selectedButtonUid === uid ? <button key={uid}> ... </button> : null;
  };


return(
 {isProject.map((p) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Typography onMouseEnter={()={_showButton(p.uid)}} onMouseLeave={_hideButton}>
                  {p.title} {_options(p.uid)}
                </Typography>
              </div>
            );
          })}
)
```